# Solaris 5.9 issue

Tags: unix, exception, solaris, strlen

Does someone know how can I fix the problem below? I'm not familiar with UNIX/Solaris in deep. I've googled it and I've found [some information](http://technopark02.blogspot.com/2006/04/solaris-null-pointer-bugs-usrlib00so1.html).

```
An unexpected exception has been detected in native code outside the VM.
Unexpected Signal : 11 occurred at PC=0xFF2B44E4
Function=strlen+0x80
Library=/usr/lib/libc.so.1

Current Java thread:
        at com.tertio.tome.Tome.init0(Native Method)
        at com.tertio.tome.TomeConfig.<init>(TomeConfig.java:42)
        at com.tertio.tome.Tome.initConfig(Tome.java:124)
        at com.tertio.tome.Tome.initConfig(Tome.java:118)
        at com.tertio.provident.rmi.server.ServerConfig.<init>(ServerConfig.java:28)
        at com.tertio.provident.cli.Cli.connect(Cli.java:38)
        at com.tertio.provident.cli.Admin.main(Admin.java:23)

Dynamic libraries:
0x10000         /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/bin/java
0xff370000      /usr/lib/libthread.so.1
0xff3fa000      /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
0xff280000      /usr/lib/libc.so.1
0xff3a0000      /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire/lib/libc_psr.so.1
0xfec00000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/client/libjvm.so
0xff230000      /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1
0xff210000      /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
0xff100000      /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
0xff1c0000      /usr/lib/libm.so.1
0xff0e0000      /usr/lib/libsched.so.1
0xff0b0000      /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
0xff070000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/native_threads/libhpi.so
0xfebd0000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/libverify.so
0xfeb90000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/libjava.so
0xff040000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/libzip.so
0xfe3b0000      /ACS/DEV/users/dvprv02/prov52/lib/libjtome.so
0xfcbb0000      /ACS/DEV/users/dvprv02/prov52/lib/libtome.so
0xfe390000      /ACS/DEV/users/dvprv02/prov52/lib/libtome_ev.so
0xfcad0000      /oracle/product/home0/jre/1.4.2/lib/sparc/libnet.so

Heap at VM Abort:
Heap
 def new generation   total 2112K, used 476K [0xf1c00000, 0xf1e20000, 0xf2310000)
  eden space 2048K,  23% used [0xf1c00000, 0xf1c77230, 0xf1e00000)
  from space 64K,   0% used [0xf1e00000, 0xf1e00000, 0xf1e10000)
  to   space 64K,   0% used [0xf1e10000, 0xf1e10000, 0xf1e20000)
 tenured generation   total 1408K, used 0K [0xf2310000, 0xf2470000, 0xf5c00000)
   the space 1408K,   0% used [0xf2310000, 0xf2310000, 0xf2310200, 0xf2470000)
 compacting perm gen  total 4096K, used 1223K [0xf5c00000, 0xf6000000, 0xf9c00000)
   the space 4096K,  29% used [0xf5c00000, 0xf5d31c80, 0xf5d31e00, 0xf6000000)

Local Time = Wed Jan 23 18:03:25 2013
Elapsed Time = 0
#
# The exception above was detected in native code outside the VM
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.4.2_03-b02 mixed mode)
#
# An error report file has been saved as hs_err_pid11057.log.
# Please refer to the file for further information.
#
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: based on the section "Current java code", it is likely to be something in the TomeConfig. Is that a config file, or a JNDI source? You'll get better help on this by replacing one of those tags with [java]. Good luck.

Comment: Signal 11 is SIGSEGV.  This appears to be caused by your code as shellter mentioned.  This often means you are referencing memory (probably by trying to place some there) outside the boundaries of a fixed-size string or other object like an array.

Comment: Thank you guys! It was in some configuration file, not dumped on this error log, but somehow related to ServerConfig.java.